# Python/Mpmath: Why don't I get any decimal points for large number division, but do for smaller numbers

Tags: python, decimal, precision

Why does the large number give me an integer (or at least no decimal points), but the smaller number give me a bunch of decimal points? Is the way I set the precision or declare the variables wrong?

```
import math
from mpmath import *
mp.prec=1000

x = 5431526412865007456
print mpf((x)/6)

ACTUAL OUTPUT: 905254402144167909.0
WANTED OUTPUT: 905254402144167909.3333333333333333333333(…)

x = 5431526413
print mpf((x)/6.)

OUTPUT: 905254402.16666662693023681640625
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `mpf(x)/6` or `mpf(x)/6.0`. The reason your code didn't work is that it did the division using Python's normal rules, *then* converted it to a arbitrary-precision number, whereas this converts it first so the division is done using arbitrary-precision math.

Comment: @Harry No problem! BTW, I have added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: `mpf` isn't fixed point. It's arbitrary-precision floating point.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oops, fixing that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Done - Thanks for the extra description!